# How to add many date ranges

Tags: usability, website-design, web-app

I'm currently sketching a report module.

The options for one value you can add are:

```
 - Object                ex New York Office
 - Device                ex My Awesome Weather Station
 - Value                 ex Ambient Temperature
 - Aggregation           AVG/MIN/MAX
```

You can add as many values as you wish.

You have to select one date range to generate your report for.

You can add as many date ranges as you want to. There will be one chart per date range.
Date Range pickers shall open a modal calendar.

This is my first try to get all under one roof without bloating the interface.

[image]

Hopefully it's already clear what you can do: First you select your date range. Then you can add a values within the table. Pressing the *tick* will add the value as text into the table and add a new row for adding a new value.

#### My actual question

What would be an intuitive way to add many date ranges?

The best idea I came up with is to *reuse* the table.

[image]

Comment: Is there a limit to the number of objects that can be added for a date range?

Comment: @Brian no limits at all. But you dont connect a specific object o an specific date range.

Comment: A really important question to ask is: how will this get used 90% of the time? The web app I work on has two datepickers for start and end dates on reports, default blank. Guess what most users do? They go back on the start date a few months and pick a day. Then they pick today for end date. It's a needless bit of user choice most of the time. We could (and should) specify `today - 3 months` and `today`. Whatever you do, provide a *reasonable default value* that takes no work from the user and covers the most common use case.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably separate this out into two separate views: Viewing the date range data, and creating/editing date ranges.

The latter might use an accordion-style setup to create blocks for the dates and create some visual/logical separation:

[image]

...where the former would present the chart data with a date range selector and a link to the editor where one could create, delete, or edit the date ranges.

[image]

Comment: This is a very nice idea and I'm voting it up, but IMHO, despite the date ranges, you should need to separate by objects rather than dates, otherwise you'll get the values for different date ranges, but mixed objects

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll let the question open for a bit though.

Answer (score 0):

I think it really depends on how often you are going to have to do this, otherwise it is no point in creating a custom control for a very specific purpose that doesn't actually get used very much at all.

One thing I thought of it to create a calendar-like widget that allows the user to click a start date and then an end date for the range, such that a single click selects or unselects the date, and a double click on the second date locks in the date range (when you have a start date selected). It would require some interaction design tweaks but I think there are plenty of airline or holiday booking website to reference from.